# How do I get Gnome-do or Ubuntu Dash to open an existing application?

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-12.04, quicksilver

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and have also installed GNOME Do as a task launcher. If I already have a Firefox browser window open, and I use my hot key to open Gnome-do and type in Firefox + enter, it opens a whole new window instead of focusing on the window I already have open.

I'm used to Mac OS X's Quicksilver where it focuses you back to the opened application if it exists already. Is that possible to replicate using GNOME Do or Ubuntu Dash?

Comment: I've also been looking for this for quite some time and there seems to be no solution that works as smooth as quicksilver. You can use gnome-do to focus a specific app with the keyword 'focus'. But you have to know if the app is started already. krunner works a bit better, but has rather heavy dependencies if you haven't already installed something from KDE. The application lens seems to be a dead end: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/1027792

Comment: BTW, your chances for a valid answer are better on http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

This may be different for a mac keyboard, but on a windows keyboard the key combination is win+numkey, with num being the order of your application in the launcher.

You can hold down the win key and get an overlay of applications, and the corresponding number to open them.

Hope that helps!